# Spectral properties of Cayley graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be a finite group. Do eigenvalues of its Cayley graph say anything about the algebraic properties of $G$? The spectrum of Cayley graph may depend on the presentation, so it's not a good invariant, but maybe something interesting can still be said here?

In the case of an infinite group, can Cayley graph be replaced by some suitable infinite-dimensional object (say, linear operator, a generalization of the graph's adjacency matrix) so that the object's spectral properties may carry some algebraic data about the group?

Comment: Asking about the eigenvalues of the Cayley graph is equivalent to asking about the eigenvalues of G in its regular representation, which decomposes in a well-understood way into the irreducible representations of G.  

Comment: Qiaochu, the spectrum does depend on the generator set used, surely?

Comment: Ah, right.  You're actually asking about the eigenvalues of some sum of elements of G acting on its regular representation.  I was a little too bold there; these eigenvalues depend on the eigenvalues of the elements of G themselves if and only if G is abelian, where the whole story is totally straightforward.

Comment: First, there are graphs which are Cayley graphs for more than one group. Second if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the Cayley relative to the generating set $G\setminus H$ is the complement of $|G:H|$ copies of the complete graph $K_{|H|}$. So in general one can tell almost nothing about the group from the Cayley graph.

Answer (score 9):

[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02925188), by A. Valette, is a survey devoted to this question, although he's more interested in infinite groups. In the infinite case, the "adjacency matrix" is a bounded operator on $\ell^2(\Gamma)$, and its spectrum makes sense. Of course, it depends on the generating set.

One of the first results he mentions is a theorem of Kesten : it is possible to recover the fact that $G$ is amenable, or free, by looking at this spectrum.

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep the references close to the question, here are two computations of the spectra of a Cayley graph:

- Lovász, L. Spectra of graphs with transitive groups. Period. Math. Hungar.  6  (1975), no. 2, 191--195. [MR0398886](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0398886)
- Babai, L. Spectra of Cayley graphs. J. Combin. Theory Ser. B  27  (1979), no. 2, 180--189. [MR0546860](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0546860)

(The prevalence of people named *László* in this list is interesting. It reminds me of a little story I recently got from Wikipedia while hunting for a reference on the Higman-Sims group: the extraordinary fact that two people named 'Higman' discovered the same sporadic simple group!)

Answer (score 3):

Just to keep the reference close to the question, I think that the manuscript of Petteri Kaski, Eigenvectors and Spectra of Cayley graphs,Helsinki university of technology, Spring Term 2002, is a very good reference.

Answer (score 2):

I know at least one special case where your second question makes sense.  If $G$ is a compact group, it has a category $\text{Rep}(G)$ of finite-dimensional unitary representations which break up into direct sums of irreducible representations.  Fix a representation $V$ such that every irreducible representation appears in $V^{\otimes n}$ for some $n$.  One can construct a graph $\Gamma(V)$ whose vertices are the irreducible representations of $G$ and where the number of edges from $A$ to $B$ is the multiplicity by which $B$ appears in $A \otimes V$.  By the assumption, $\Gamma(V)$ is connected, and its combinatorial properties encode information about the behavior of the tensor powers of $V$, hence behavior about $G$.

When $G$ is finite, this graph has the property that its eigenvalues are precisely the character values $\chi_V(g)$ as $g$ runs through all conjugacy classes.  But the great thing is that this statement still makes sense even when $G$ is infinite in a sense which is made precise [in this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/walks-on-graphs-and-tensor-products/).

Finally, if $G$ is abelian, all of the finite-dimensional irreducible representations are one-dimensional.  They can be identified with the [Pontryagin dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) $G^{\vee}$, which is discrete, and $\Gamma(V)$ becomes precisely the Cayley graph of $G^{\vee}$ with respect to the generators that make up $V$!  So this is one sense in which the Cayley graph of an infinite group gives you algebraic data, but about its **dual** group.

Answer (score 2):

There is the paper [Property (T) and Kazhdan constants for discrete groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00039-003-0425-8) by Andrzej Żuk, which gives a sufficient criterion for property (T) in terms of some spectral properties of a graph depending on a group $G$ with a generating set $S$.  This graph is not the Cayley graph. But maybe it is still in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for other reference, we showed that a finite DS group is solvable, and every non-cyclic Sylow subgroup of a finite DS group is of order $4$, $8$, $16$ or $9$. You can find more results in the below link:
https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0219498816501759

In these cases, the DS property of Cayley graphs of a group can say something about its structure.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a recent survey (preprint) on eigenvalues of Cayley (di)graphs.

Liu and Zhou, Eigenvalues of Cayley graphs (2022), Preprint link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.09829.pdf