# Number of ways to write a group element as a product of generators

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group generated by some finite set $S = \{g_1, g_2, ...\} \subseteq G$. Let $h \in G$ be some element. Let the function $c_n: G \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined that $c_n(h)$  is the number of ways of writing $h$ as a product of $n$ elements from $S$.

Has this function been studied in the literature? Are there known results of the forms this function can take and growth rates it exhibits, based on the choice of $G, S, h$?

Comment: $c_n(h)$ is counting the number of words in a regular language and so has a rational generating function and either polynomial or exponential growth. Your automaton is the Cayley graph of G with initial state 1 and accepting state h

Comment: Here is a related question about the spectra of Cayley graphs of finite groups. https://mathoverflow.net/q/18212/22277